# How can I injector Angular module in webpack?

Tags: angularjs, commonjs, webpack

I install **ngRoute** from **npm**, my webpack default load `default.js`

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require("webpack"),
    AngularPlugin = require('angular-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    root: [path.join(__dirname, "bower_components")]
  },
  plugins: [
  new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
    [new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])],
    ["normal", "loader"]
  ),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "windows.jQuery": "jquery",
      _: "underscore"
  }),
  new AngularPlugin()
  ],
  entry: {
    all: "./app/assets/javascript/default",
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/assets/javascript',
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js"
  },
}
```

**default.js**

```
 // default.js
 'use strict';

 require('angular-route');
 require('./angularLoad')();
```

**angularLoad.js**

```
// angularLoad.js
module.exports = function () {
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
   app.controller('ctroe', function(){
     console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaa");
   });
};
```

When I run webpack, get an error message:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'ngRoute' in....

This error when the angular injection. Have any suggestions? Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an alias from `ngRoute` to `angular-route` like this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'ngRoute': 'angular-route'
    }
}
```